# Multiple inheritance from instantiations of template class and what about access to member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

Let's take a look at the code:

```
template <typename C>
class S {
public:
    void add (C c) { ++cnt; }
    size_t size () const { return cnt; }

private:
    size_t cnt {}; 
};

struct Foo1 {};
struct Foo2 {};
struct Foo3 {};

class Z : public S<Foo1>, public S<Foo2>, public S<Foo3> {
public:
    using S<Foo1>::add;
    using S<Foo2>::add;
    using S<Foo3>::add;

    using S<Foo1>::size;    // (1)
    using S<Foo2>::size;    // (2)
    using S<Foo3>::size;    // (3)
};
```

And usage looks like this:

```
Z z;

z.add (Foo1 {});
z.add (Foo1 {});
z.add (Foo2 {});

cout << z.size () << endl;
```

This code compiles fine with gcc-5.1 (c++11), but this code does not compile under clang-3.5 (c++11 - sorry, I do not have newer version of clang).

Clang produces **"error: call to member function 'size' is ambiguous"** which is basically (from my point of view) correct, but gcc compiles it and returns **2**.

Ok, but here is much more fun, if I switch the order of lines marked with comments (1) and (2), to get something like this:

```
using S<Foo2>::size;    // (2)
using S<Foo1>::size;    // (1)
```

The code still compiles on gcc and the result is: **1**.

As you can imagine, if you write line (3) before these two, you will get **0**.

So, from what I see, gcc gets first using declaration of **S<C>::size**, ignores rest of them and uses this one.

Could anybody tell me which compiler is doing correct work according to the C++ standard?

Reported at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66698

Best,
Artur

Comment: [Wandbox link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EMKWrvy558kzZmQD). Seems like it was an error in 4.6.4.

Comment: Obviously, your code is ambiguous and should not compile.  The error reported by clang is correct.  MSVC also reports the invalid ambiguity.  You should report the error.

Answer (score 1):

It's a gcc bug.  Clang and MSVC correctly flag the ambiguity.

If you remove the 3 using statements, the compilation fails (as it should) because of ambiguity:

```
prog.cpp:39:12: error: request for member 'size' is ambiguous
  cout << z.size () << endl; return 0;
            ^
prog.cpp:9:12: note: candidates are: size_t S<C>::size() const [with C = Foo3; size_t = unsigned int]
     size_t size () const { cout<<typeid(C).name()<<endl; return cnt; }
            ^
prog.cpp:9:12: note:                 size_t S<C>::size() const [with C = Foo2; size_t = unsigned int]
prog.cpp:9:12: note:                 size_t S<C>::size() const [with C = Foo1; size_t = unsigned int]
```

According to the standard member lookup algorithm, despite the using decalartions you should come to the same results:

> **10.2/3:** (...) In the declaration set, using-declarations are replaced by the members they designate, and type declarations (including
>   injected-class-names) are replaced by the types they designate.

I couldn't find an exact match for this bug.  I'd suggest that you [report it](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/).